# How to join a windows machine to an AD domain automatically?

Tags: windows, active-directory, ansible, packer

I can add any user to a windows ISO using packer and add that user to the local administrators group. The question what is the best way to automate the step of joining a newly created windows machine to the AD domain. I prefer Ansible, although don't know hot to do that using Ansible.

Comment: We are always glad to help, but a question of this nature would probably be more appropriate within the [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) community.

Comment: I checked on meta before add this here.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that there is already an Ansible playbook for that.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_domain_membership_module.html